# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java

Есть цикл:

```
ArrayList<String> all_folders;
ArrayList<String> vvv = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < all_folders.size(); i++)
{
    vvv = follist(all_folders.get(i));
    for (int a = 0; a < vvv.size(); a++)
    {
        all_music.add(vvv.get(a) + "");
    }
}
```

Он рабочий, только `all_music.add(vvv.get(a) + "")` выдаёт ошибку.

Код метода `follist`:

```
public ArrayList<String> follist(String f)
{
    File rootsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dcim = new File(f);
    ArrayList title = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] imagelist = dcim.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
            return ((name.endsWith(".mp3")));
        }
    });

    if (imagelist != null)
    {
        data = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++)
        {
            data.add(imagelist[i]);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Что означает слово «рабочий», если вы жалуетесь, что код _не_  работает?

Comment: А какого типа `all_music`?

Comment: Рабочий значит, что безall_music.add(vvv.get(a) + "") работает, даже если написать all_music.add(a+"") работает all_music как и vvv Array массив

Comment: `vvv.get(a) + ""` - Что вы пытаетесь сделать этим действием?

Comment: Добавить в массив all_music элемент масива vvv под номером а. Вообще у меня есть массив all_folders это пути к папкам. Функция follist(string) возвращает масив с данными в папке. Мне нужно в один массив собрать все данные из папок all_folders

Comment: Что возвращает `follist()`? Случайно не raw `ArrayList`, элементы которого реально имеют тип `java.io.File`?

Comment: Да, возвращает Arraylist с путями к файлам

Comment: @Etki я думаю, это неявный `toString()`

Comment: И что мне делать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin хотелось бы услышать автора

Comment: Покажите код метода `follist()`.

Comment: @antonin14d что делать? ответьте на вопросы в комментариях. :)

Comment: public ArrayList<String> follist(String f){
 File rootsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File dcim = new File(f);
    ArrayList title = new ArrayList<String>();
 File[] imagelist = dcim.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
  {
   public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
   {
    return ((name.endsWith(".mp3")));
   }
  });


 if (imagelist != null)
 {
 data = new ArrayList<String>();

  for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++)
  {
   
   data.add(imagelist[i]);
  }
}

return data;
 }

Comment: @antonin14d не надо кода в комментариях. Добавьте код в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.add(imagelist[i]);
```

Вы кладете в коллекцию `data = new ArrayList<String>()`, хранящую строки, элемент массива `File[] imagelist`.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил data.add(imagelist[i].toString); Все работает

Answer (score 0):

Вангую, что

1. `all_music` это `ArrayList<String>`
2. вы хотели преобразовать в строку.

Тогда:

```
ArrayList<String> all_folders;
for (int i = 0; i < all_folders.size(); i++)
{
    ArrayList<String> vvv = follist(all_folders.get(i));
    for (int a = 0; a < vvv.size(); a++)
    {
        all_music.add(vvv.get(a).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: На даче, пишу с березового полена, форматирования не вижу. Если там криво, поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Дописал .toString ,  не помогло. Я думал что  в Arraylist<String> и так строки

Comment: `System.out.println(vvv.get(0).class);` что пишет?

Comment: @antonin14d в нем-то строки, но вы вроде где-то File туда кладете.